# Control 'ctl00_TextBox1' of type 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

When a form with a run at server is added there will be two forms with runat server and another error occurs. Can some one give me an idea. Thankx in advance.

The details of the error are as follows.

Control 'ctl00_TextBox1' of type 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Control 'ctl00_TextBox1' of type 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [HttpException (0x80004005): Control
>   'ctl00_TextBox1' of type 'TextBox'
>   must be placed inside a form tag with
>   runat=server.]
>   System.Web.UI.Page.VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control
>   control) +2052287
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox.AddAttributesToRender(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +49
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +17
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +17
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +25
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +121
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +22
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ICollection children) +199
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +20
>   System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +7
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +25
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +121
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +22
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ICollection children) +199
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +20
>   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +26
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +25
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +121
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +22
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2558
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:2.0.50727.1873;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.1433

Comment: In case any of the answers posted for your question helped, please accept them. Or you can also add an answer from your end that you think solved your problem.

Answer (score 11):

The error states the problem

Correct

```
<form id="frm" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox id="txt" runat="server" />
</form>
```

Incorrect

```
<asp:TextBox id="txt" runat="server" />
<form id="frm" runat="server">
</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

Seeing the tag "master-pages" included in the question, this error may pop up when you are trying to dynamically add text boxes (or for that matter, any control) in a content page which uses a master page.

Only the master page contains a form with runat="server" set. The content pages only have content place holders.

To dynamically add controls to a content page, include a panel in your desired contentplaceholder in your content page and then add controls to it in your code. For example,

In your aspx file for the content page, add a panel like

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
</asp:Panel>
```

Then, in your code behind,

```
        Dim txtbox As New textbox()
        Panel1.Controls.Add(txtbox)
```

Answer (score 1):

Error happens because you placed your control with runat="server" outside the form tag (with runat="server" too). ASP.NET requires to have all server controls inside one form with runat="server" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

With standard ASP.Net, you can only have one form. Thats a limitation of ASP.Net. If youre going to be doing stuff that requires 2 or more `<FORM>` tags, you'll need MVC or something along the lines of.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this too.  What I did, was just added a PageWrapper , and all the site's code went inside that. For example:

```
<body>
 <div ID="PageWrapper">
    <form ID="form1" runat="server">
        <div ID="Header">...</div>
        <div ID="MainContent">...</div>
         ...
    </form>
 </div>
</body>
```

Something like that.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You did not say where this control is on your form.

If this error is a result of another control being inside a GridView control like I had, then this may help you, too:

[Control xxx of type 'LinkButton' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28155089/153923)

Answer (score 0):

Error is Control 'txtTo' of type 'TextBox' which must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

ERROR is This Code.

```
      <tr>
          <td class="style1">
                <strong>To </strong>
            </td>
            <td class="style2">
                <strong>: </strong>
            </td>
            <td class="style6">
                &nbsp;
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTo" runat="server" Width="475px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

both the control and the form tag must have `runat="server"`