# Control xxx of type 'LinkButton' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datagrid

I have a [DataGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx) that I am trying to export when an ASP.NET [Button](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.aspx) is clicked.

[image: error screen]

The exact error is:

> Control 'ctl00_body_RollupDG_ctl02_btnShowGLdetail' of type 'LinkButton' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

I found similar questions on here, but all seem to indicate that this comes from the ASP.NET control **NOT** being placed within a [ContentPlaceHolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.contentplaceholder.aspx) or a *ContentPlaceHolder* **NOT** being placed within a RunAt Server form.

I have both of these, so that is not the case here.

My **ExportExcelFile** method catches the [HttpException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpexception.aspx) at [RenderControl()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk91d11a.aspx) (as shown in the screenshot above). That code is as follows:

```
protected void ExportExcelFile(object Sender, EventArgs e) { //export to excel
    var grdResults = (periodCriteria.SelectedValue == "year") ? RollupDG : QuarterDG;
    var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.Clear();
    response.Charset = String.Empty;
    response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=GlBudgetReport.xls");
    using (var sw = new StringWriter()) {
        using (var htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw)) {
            grdResults.RenderControl(htw);
            response.Write(sw.ToString());
            response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

As shown in my **Find Results** box below, there are several ASP.NET [LinkButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx) controls, but each of them does contain the `runat="server"` clause.

[image: Find Results]

It appears the *LinkButton* data in the *DataGrid* has difficulty rendering as **Plain Text**.

If not, is there something in my export method that can be configured so that the DataGrid data is all interpreted as text?

I could create a blank DataGrid, then walk through the filled DataGrid, writing in only the text of each field - but I only want to do this if it is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you just need to override the method that checks for a form. You don't need to add any logic to the method. Just add the following to your code behind:

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control) { }
```

ETA: You may also need to set `EnableEventValidation="false"` in the `<%@Page />` element.

Comment: Interesting. I added that line, and it changed the error to [InvalidOperationException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx): *RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render();*

Comment: However, I was able to look up [EnableEventValidation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation.aspx), found [Syed's Post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17058409/153923), and got it to working! Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. I updated the answer to include this piece.