# How can I make a file generated on a web page available to the user as a download?

Tags: c#, jquery, sharepoint-2010, itext, filesaver.js

This question is related to one I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31526854/how-can-i-prompt-the-user-for-a-save-location-from-a-sharepoint-page) on "How can I prompt the user for a save location from a Sharepoint page?"

What I need to do is, after generating a PDF thus:

```
        private void GeneratePDF(List<ListColumns> listOfListItems)
        {
            . . .
            //Create a stream that we can write to, in this case a MemoryStream
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 10, 10)) 
                {
                    //Create a writer that's bound to our PDF abstraction and our stream
                    using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
                    {

                        //Open the document for writing
                        doc.Open();

                        Paragraph docTitle = new Paragraph("UCSC - Direct Payment Form", timesBold16UCSCBlue);
                        doc.Add(docTitle);

                        Paragraph subTitle = new Paragraph("(Not to be used for reimbursement of services)", timesRoman9Font);
                        subTitle.IndentationLeft = 20;
                        doc.Add(subTitle);

                        . . . // tons of iTextSharp PDF-generation code elided for brevity

                        String htmlToRenderAsPDF = sb.ToString();

                        //XMLWorker also reads from a TextReader and not directly from a string
                        using (var srHtml = new StringReader(htmlToRenderAsPDF))
                        {
                            XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, srHtml);
                        }

                        doc.Close();
                    }
                }
                try
                {
                    var bytes = ms.ToArray();
                    // This is currently saved to a location on the server such as C:\Users\TEMP.SP.005\Desktop\iTextSharpTest.pdf (but the number (such as 
"005" irregularly increments))
                    String pdfFileID = GetYYYYMMDDAndUserNameAndAmount();
                    String pdfFileName = String.Format("DirectPayDynamic_{0}.pdf", pdfFileID);
                    String fileFullpath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), pdfFileName);
                    String fileLinkBase = "Generated PDF: <a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>";
                    String filelink = String.Format(fileLinkBase, fileFullpath, pdfFileName);
                    File.WriteAllBytes(fileFullpath, bytes);

                    var pdflink = new Label
                    {
                        CssClass = "finaff-webform-field-label",
                        Text = filelink
                    };
                    this.Controls.Add(pdflink);
                }
                catch (DocumentException dex)
                {
                    throw (dex);
                }
                catch (IOException ioex)
                {
                    throw (ioex);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw (ex);
                }
            }
        } // GeneratePDF
```

...afford the user the opportunity to save that file to their local machine (currently, it is being saved on the server).

IOW, what I basically want to do is replace this line:

```
String fileFullpath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), pdfFileName);
```

...with something like:

```
String fileFullpath = "Hey, bloke (or blokette), where do you want to save this?"
```

This is obviously possible, and even somewhat common, as many websites will generate files for you and then allow you to save those

generated files to either a location you select or a default location, such as your downloads folder.

Either a server-side (C#) or a client-side (jQuery) solution is acceptable, although I prefer server-side, as that is where the PDF is being generated.

Comment: Get rid of your `catch` blocks.

Comment: Your server cannot write to the user's disk.  Instead, you need to serve the file over the HTTP response as a download.

Comment: Why? (get rid of my catch blocks)

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do - make the file available for download. I will update the question title.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2999314/34397

Comment: I'd further add to what @SLaks said about `try/catch` and say that you should only `try` something, and as little as possible of that something, that can fail, and only `try` it if you have an explicit recovery plan in place that's different than the default. Your code is trying 11-ish things including calling `ToArray()` on a `MemoryStream` which should never throw unless a cosmic ray hits the machine and also setting strings which uses your own logic and isn't explicitly handled in the `catch` statements anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I had to force an Excel spreadsheet to download to the client, I used this code, which may point you to where you are wanting to get:

[Control xxx of type 'LinkButton' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28155089/153923)

```
protected void ExportExcelFile(object Sender, EventArgs e) { //export to excel
        var grdResults = new DataGrid(); // REF: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28155089/153923
        if (periodCriteria.SelectedValue == "year") {
            grdResults = RollupDG;
        } else {
            grdResults = QuarterDG;
        }
        var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.Clear();
        response.Charset = String.Empty;
        response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=GlBudgetReport.xls");
        using (var sw = new StringWriter()) {
            using (var htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw)) {
                grdResults.RenderControl(htw);
                response.Write(sw.ToString());
                response.End();
            }
        }
}
```