# ASP.NET Add Dynamic HTML w/ UpdatePanel & Web Controls to aspx page. Web Control update other control OnClick

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, updatepanel, master-pages

I am trying to add a series of `UpdatePanels` with a `CheckBox` and `<a>` link in each.  When I click the  link I want the cooresponding `CheckBox` next to it to become checked as well. I can get the HTML to show up properly but am having issues getting the `UpdatePanel` & controls communicating with the backend.

I have a main Master page, a 2nd Master page inside the main one, then my content page I'm working with inside the child Master page.  I have a ScriptManager on my main Master page with `EnablePartialRendering="True"`.

**I get this error: asp.net CS1061**
Which basically means my Control isn't finding my function in the code behind

The amount of these sections I'm creating to include the UpdatePanel is dynamic and dependent on the number of results from the Database.  I am trying to do this utilizing ASP.NETs features without resorting to Javascript

aspx page:

```
<asp:Content ID="aBody" ContentPlaceHolderID="aContent" runat="server">
   <div id="caJumbotron" class="jumbotron aJumbotron" runat="server" >
       <asp:Label ID="auditsTable" runat="server" Text="" />
   </div>
</asp:Content>
```

aspx.cs:  HTML code inside a loop

```
HTML += "<div class='row caSectionRow'>" +
            "<div class='col-md-6'>" +
                "<asp:UpdatePanel runat='server'>" +
                    "<ContentTemplate>" +
                        "<input type='checkbox' class='caCheckbox' name='" + dt.Rows[i]["NAME"].ToString() + "' id='" + dt.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString() + "' value='" + dt.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString() + "' > " +
                        "<a href='' class='caLink' OnClick ='AuditLinkClick' runat='server' >" + dt.Rows[i]["NAME"].ToString() + "</a>" +
                    "</ContentTemplate>" +
                "</asp:UpdatePanel>" +
            "</div>"; //Insert column data
```

Then insert the dynamic HTML inside the label:

```
auditsTable.Text = HTML;
```

My last question would be... I'm wanting to make the link's OnClick event to AuditLinkClick in the backend update the CheckBox to checked.  But the checkbox will have a dynamic ID and the sender to the function will be the link.  How would I check the CheckBox inside the same UpdatePanel as the link clicked?

```
    private void AuditLinkClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("HERE<br/>");
        //Link is what sent us here
        CheckBox btn = (CheckBox)sender;
        string id = btn.ID;
        btn.Checked = true;
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are trying to add dynamic controls to a page by creating a string. That will never work. You need to create REAL controls and add them to a placeholder.

Comment: Ok.  I think I understand and will work on this without adding them as a string.  I tried going this way once but was confusing how to add an UpdatePanel.  Because after you add it, how do you distinguish when the UpdatePanel ends?

Comment: Then again, maybe I should rest with one UpdatePanel and add the controls to it...

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563426/how-to-dynamically-create-asp-net-controls-within-dynamically-created-asp-net-co) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43731772/i-need-to-get-value-on-button-click-from-dynamic-control-which-was-generated-on) how to deal with dynamic controls

Answer (score 0):

@VDWWD was correct in the comments (Thanks!).  I could not add Dynamic Controls to the page as a string.  This is what I did and how I broke it down:

Put a single `UpdatePanel` in the front end with a `Panel` to hold all of the dynamic data I am adding:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelCheckBoxes" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="caPanel" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In the Code Behind I added each control and the framework `<div>` s around them by:

```
caPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='col-md-6'>"));

CheckBox aCheckBox = new CheckBox();
aCheckBox.ID = dt.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString();
caPanel.Controls.Add(aCheckBox);

Button checkboxButton = new Button();
checkboxButton.ID = "Button"+dt.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString();
checkboxButton.Text = dt.Rows[i]["NAME"].ToString();
checkboxButton.CssClass = "caButton";
checkboxButton.Click += new EventHandler(ALinkClick);
caPanel.Controls.Add(checkboxButton);

caPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
```

One thing that held me back from discovering this sooner was the fact that I'm using Master Pages and needed to use a `Panel` to add the Controls to.  I was getting the error **[HttpException (0x80004005): Control 'ctl00_TextBox1' of type 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.]** until I used the `Panel`.

This answer helped: [Control 'ctl00_TextBox1' of type 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490340/control-ctl00-textbox1-of-type-textbox-must-be-placed-inside-a-form-tag-with)